# MikTex 2.9 Error: A requested feature, protocol or option was not found built-in in this libcurl due to a build-time decision

Tags: errors, miktex, miktex2.9, miktex-update

Recently my (previously working) MiKTex installation started giving me the following error, when trying to install a package and updating. Does anyone have an idea what to do about this? I am on windows 10, and tried reinstalling several times already. I am also behind a proxy/vpn which wasn't a problem before... Any help would be appreciated.

```
MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: A requested feature, protocol or option was not found built-in in this libcurl due to a build-time decision.
Data: 
Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\CurlWebSession.cpp
Line: 348
MiKTeX: 2.9
OS: Windows 10 Enterprise, 64-bit, build 10586
Invokers: non-existing/explorer
SystemAdmin: no
PowerUser: no
Root0: C:\Users\~\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
Root2: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Root3: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
UserInstall: C:\Users\~\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserConfig: C:\Users\~\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserData: C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
```

Comment: Did you do a google for "Message: A requested feature, protocol or option was not found built-in in this libcurl due to a build-time decision." Maybe https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/5655 gives a hint or one of the other hits.hits

Comment: Ask on the github issue tracker of miktex.

Comment: Apparently a never seen before "system dependent" problem. https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/125#event-1603472840.